# Importing CSV quoting error is driving me nuts

Tags: ruby, csv

I've been having an unbelievable time trying to import a CSV file in ruby-1.9.2.

The file I am trying to parse has:

- commas within columns
- quotes within columns
- uses an '@' as the :col_sep

csv.txt (representative input, real one is 101k lines):

```
㔾@㔾@jié@"seal" radical in Chinese characters, (Kangxi radical 26)
```

My code:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("/Users/adam/Desktop/csvtest.txt", {:col_sep => "@"}) do |row|
    puts row.to_s 
end
```

My desired output:

```
["㔾", "㔾", "jié", "\"seal\" radical in Chinese characters, (Kangxi radical 26)"]
```

What I get for output:

```
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unclosed quoted field on line 1.
from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/CSV.rb:1910:in `block in shift'
from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/CSV.rb:1825:in `loop'
from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/CSV.rb:1825:in `shift'
from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/CSV.rb:1767:in `each'
from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/CSV.rb:1202:in `block in foreach'
from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/CSV.rb:1340:in `open'
from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/CSV.rb:1201:in `foreach'
from (irb):31
from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

It says there are unclosed quoted feilds, but I can see that the quotes open and close.

Escaping the quotes does nothing. I get the same error (`...@""seal"" r...`).
Changing them to single quotes makes it work (`...@'seal' r...`).
The problem is I NEED them to be in double quotes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ruby's CSV library really does seem poorly designed

Answer (score 58):

I think the problem is that CSV is trying to interpret `"seal"` as a single quoted column; but, it doesn't appear as `@"seal"@` so the parser gets confused because quotes are supposed to surround columns. I don't see any option to tell CSV that the columns aren't quoted but you can kludge around it by setting `:quote_char` to something that will never occur. If you're using UTF-8 then you can safely use a zero byte as your "quote character that will never occur":

```
CSV.foreach(filename, :col_sep => "@", :quote_char => "\x00") do |row|
    #...
end
```

This should work as long as none of your columns are quoted.

Comment: +1 The CSV spec. is so completely abused and ignored, similarly to HTML. For both, there are times I resort to fixing the data before I hand it off to the parser. I think that'd be a solution for this problem too, but I like how you're fooling the parser with `quote_char => "\x00"`. Nice job.

Comment: I have UTF-16 coming from a `bcp` MSSQL dump which actually has the nul character. Just for fun I picked the snowman character (☃) as an alternate. :)