# How can I read CSV with no quote_char in ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, double-quotes

I have a TSV file with no quote chars. Whenever a `\t` occurs in the data, it is always to separate columns, and never a part of a column value. Whenever a `"` occurs, it is always a part of a column value, and never to enclose column values.

I would like to read this CSV in Ruby but it gives me

```
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1925:in `block (2 levels) in shift': Illegal quoting in line 9506. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)
```

My code is:

```
CSV.foreach(input_file, { :col_sep => "\t", :headers => true}) do |row|
   puts row
end
```

Any way to get around this problem?

Comment: I highly recommend the fastercsv gem by James Edward Gray II.  It makes life simpler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing CSV quoting error is driving me nuts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073920/importing-csv-quoting-error-is-driving-me-nuts)

Comment: @6ftDan: The standard library csv in Ruby 1.9.3 *is* fastercsv AFAIK.

Answer (score 31):

Turns out I could fix it by putting `quote_char => "\x00"` to trick it into thinking the zero byte is the quote char.

Answer (score 3):

The [`liberal_parsing` option](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) is available for cases like this. From the documentation:

> When set to a true value, CSV will attempt to parse input not conformant with RFC 4180, such as double quotes in unquoted fields.

In your example this would be:

```
CSV.foreach(input_file, { :col_sep => "\t", :headers => true, :liberal_parsing => true }) do |row|
  puts row
end
```