# Ruby CSV fails on fields like ="1234"

Tags: ruby, csv

I need to import/update/export CSV files which contain fields starting with an equals sign.

```
...,="20042",...
```

From reading on the web, that is an Excel trick to force a number to stay as a string type (Excel would see digits and auto-format it to a number).

Ruby fails on this:

```
ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1925:in `block (2 levels) in shift': Illegal quoting in line 1. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)
```

Seems reasonable.

What is the best way to handle this? Pre-process the file to remove the =?

Here's an full row example:

```
"Product Code","Product Name","Retail Price","Tax Percentage","Option Name","Option Type"
="20042","Blossom Wall Art","245.00",="1","",""
```

Comment: How you want your data to format ? I will think after your feedback. :-)

Comment: Can you give atleast 2 rows..? So that I can try..

Comment: Can you supply a complete row so that we can see what the quoting is really like? The options you're using with the CSV parser would also be useful. This might be the as problem as [**Importing CSV quoting error is driving me nuts**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8073920/479863).

Comment: I've added a full row example. Note that twice 2 fields start with =. Does CSV library have a hook to assist, or pre-parse the whole file prior to using CSV library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub` should be enough:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'

data = File.read('file.csv').gsub(/=("[^"]*")/, '\\1')

CSV.parse(data).each do |e|
  puts e.inspect
end
```

Output:

```
["Product Code", "Product Name", "Retail Price", "Tax Percentage", "Option Name", "Option Type"]
["20042", "Blossom Wall Art", "245.00", "1", "", ""]
```